# Store .txt files into Mysql as Blob from ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, blob

Currently I'm Working on ASP.NET MVC 3 Project. I need to Store text(.txt) files into MySQL as Blob. MySQL is New to me.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ashush/working-with-binary-large-objects-blobs/) (Connectionstring should be modified):

```
string filePath = @"C:\\MyFile.ext";

//A stream of bytes that represnts the binary file
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

//The reader reads the binary data from the file stream
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);

//Bytes from the binary reader stored in BlobValue array
byte[] BlobValue = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

fs.Close();
reader.Close();

SqlConnection BlobsDatabaseConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = BlobsDatabase; Integrated Security = SSPI");
SqlCommand SaveBlobeCommand = new SqlCommand();
SaveBlobeCommand.Connection = BlobsDatabaseConn;
SaveBlobeCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SaveBlobeCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BlobsTable(BlobFileName, BlobFile)" + "VALUES (@BlobFileName, @BlobFile)";

SqlParameter BlobFileNameParam = new SqlParameter("@BlobFileName", SqlDbType.NChar); 
SqlParameter BlobFileParam = new SqlParameter("@BlobFile", SqlDbType.Binary);
SaveBlobeCommand.Parameters.Add(BlobFileNameParam);
SaveBlobeCommand.Parameters.Add(BlobFileParam);
BlobFileNameParam.Value = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
BlobFileParam.Value = BlobValue;
try
{
    SaveBlobeCommand.Connection.Open();
    SaveBlobeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(BlobFileNameParam.Value.ToString() + " saved to database.","BLOB Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

catch(Exception ex) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}

finally 
{
    SaveBlobeCommand.Connection.Close();
}
```

Take a look at:

[Writing BLOB Values to a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)